# androidstudio падает при запуске эмулятора

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, эмулятор, android-emulator

На чистом проекте запускаю только созданный эмулятор.

> #com.android.adblib.impl.SyncSendHandler - device:serial-emulator-5554,sync:SEND -
> AdbInputFileChannel("C:\Program Files\Android\Android
> Studio\plugins\android\resources\process-tracker-agent\native\x86\process-tracker")
> -> "/data/local/tmp/.studio/process-tracker"
>
> STDERR - Exception in thread "Thread-121"
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already resumed, but proposed with
> update CompletedExceptionally[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already
> resumed, but proposed with update -1]
>
> STDERR -  at
> kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.alreadyResumedError(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:482)
>
> STDERR -  at
> kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:447)
>
> STDERR -  at
> kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
>
> STDERR -  at
> kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:328)
>
> STDERR -  at
> com.android.adblib.impl.channels.ChannelReadOrWriteHandler.completionHandlerCompleted(ChannelReadOrWriteHandler.kt:149)
>
> STDERR -  at
> com.android.adblib.impl.channels.ChannelReadOrWriteHandler.access$completionHandlerCompleted(ChannelReadOrWriteHandler.kt:48)
>
> STDERR -  at
> com.android.adblib.impl.channels.ChannelReadOrWriteHandler$completionHandler$1.completed(ChannelReadOrWriteHandler.kt:57)
>
> STDERR -  at
> com.android.adblib.impl.channels.ChannelReadOrWriteHandler$completionHandler$1.completed(ChannelReadOrWriteHandler.kt:55)
>
> STDERR -  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:129)
>
> STDERR -  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:160)
>
> STDERR -  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:188)
>
> STDERR -  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:300)
>
> STDERR -  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl$ReadTask.failed(WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.java:496)
>
> STDERR -  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.PendingIoCache$1.run(PendingIoCache.java:155)
>
> STDERR -  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:113)
>
> STDERR -  at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
>
> STDERR -  at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>
> STDERR -  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Перепробовал несколько эмуляторов.

Недавно все работало. Ничего не менял в конфигурации компа. Тут же на stackoverflow нашел, что функцию вызывающую ошибку, можно проапдейтить. Но я в котлине не силен, не понимаю от кого CancellableContinuationImpl.kt и как его пересобрать. Ну и почему ошибка - непонятно

Comment: Не понятно зачем вам знать Котлин, раз у вас Студия падает или Эмулятор. Переставьте их заново.

Comment: Я уже и игуану версию пробовал ставить и последнюю версию с нуля. Падает студия при запуске эмулятора на пустом проекте, потом при работающем эмуляторе тоже падает сразу после открытия. Если закрыть эмулятор, то запускается. Не пойму в какую сторону копать.Котлин для исправления ошибки, с которой падает студия.

Comment: Напишите им в поддержку.

Comment: Дайте ссылку что вы нашли и что собираетесь патчить. Очень интересно. Жирафа 2022.3.1 Patch 2 последняя стабильная версия. Не стоит использовать canary и даже beta версии, они бывает падают.

Comment: Electric Eel стабильно работает, все, что старше - падает. Но в нем старый перечень образов для эмулятора, который зашит((, и, что очень странно, один и тот же эмулятор по разному работает в разных версиях андроид студио. В свежих виртуальная камера работает, в старой нет(

Comment: Нет никаких "зашитых" образов в AS. Она идет при скачивании в комплекте с актуальной на момент выпуска версией Android SDK, который можно скачать отдельно, который обновляется отдельно от AS.

Comment: Образы - да. А список устройств я не нашел как обновить. Правда, я не разбирался, на что профиль устройства влияет, но один тот же образ на pixel 7 из новой студии и pixel 6 из старой работают по разному с виртуальной камерой.

Comment: Android Flamingo was stable. Early builds of Android Giraffe (canary editions) was stable.
And after that some indirect-handed engineers in Jetbrains made something, so Studio don't catch exception of ADB library and crashes at whole

Comment: i have reported to google, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/309222253, they changed its priority to p1, hope will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в наличии антивируса касперского. Его отключения недостаточно, нужно обязательное его удаление. Пруфы

1. https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/309222253#comment9
2. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/305978188#comment88

и как оказалось, это не впервые такие косяки со стороны касперского https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/305978188#comment90

Гугл не будет решать эту проблему и закрыл тикет https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/309222253#comment10

Comment: тот случай, когда для корректной работы spyware надо править не код spyware, а код антивируса.

Comment: Да, Касперский на сервере стоит. Проверять удалением не буду.